# Crash on Startup: Xcodebuild's Archive command adds symbolic links to frameworks in place of actual files

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I have a Jenkins CI setup where xcodebuild would be run to produce the IPA files for my iOS project. Lately we have made a change to cocoapods setup that causes the app to crash at startup.

The change was the decision to build the pods as frameworks instead of static libraries.

Now when I open the generated .app folder and peek inside, I could see a Frameworks directory with each of the pods inside. More notably, the actual frameworks didn't make it to these folders. Instead, they are symbolic links pointing to the actual file in `DerivedData/AppName-xxxx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts`.

[image: Inside the .app product]

This will cause a crash on app startup in which the log will say something like "The framework wasn't loaded".

I've tried several xcodebuild params from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) such as `SKIP_INSTALL=YES` without much success. Also I must note that doing the Archive command from the Xcode UI will not result in this problem.

Comment: Have you ever solved this? In my case I need `SKIP_INSTALL=NO` so that's not a valid workaround anyway.