# Crashlytics asks for provisioned device's UDID when using submit

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

When I use the below command specifying the path to the IPA, upon upload success and checking the download page from Mobile Safari I get a message that seems to say that my device wasn't provisioned to download the app when it fact it was.

```
PATH_TO_CRASHLYTICS/Crashlytics.framework/submit ${API_KEY} ${API_SECRET} -ipaPath ${IPA_PATH}
```

[image: Needs to add this device's UDID to a build]

If I omit the `-ipaPath` parameter (which presumes that there's an xcarchive file generated) but not only will the upload succeed, I can get the build to be downloaded to my device without the above error message.

Comment: Sounds like not using `-ipaPath` is the way to go then?  I think you'll want that anyway in order upload the dSYM anyway?

Comment: That's right but I am having other issues when xcode archive is used, as written here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33209961/328948

Answer (score 1):

Fabric/Firebaser here!

For visibility for other members of the Fabric community, I believe adding the UDID should be the correct resolution path here.

Also, following this [link](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) would provide you the correct run script build phase to have your dSYM uploaded without needing to add the -ipaPath parameter.